# I do not understand how create hight order suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What should the function look like? I would like create PageKeyDataSourceFactory.

```
class PageKeyDataSourceFactory(
    private var request: suspend (offset: Int) -> MutableList<Any>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can be a suspend function. It must accept an `Int` as parameter and return a `MutableList<Any>`

```kotlin
var request: suspend (Int) -> ArrayList<Any>
    =  { offset: Int -> arrayListOf<Any>() }
```